# android millenial ads width issue

Tags: android, size, ads

I use millenial ads in my application. I've set android:layout_width="320dp" and I've tried using and android:layout_width="fill_parent", but it seems that almost every time the ad's width is larger than screen width and a horizontal scrollbar appear. Do you know how to fix this? I want my ad to have the exact size I've set in xml file. Thans

Comment: Is this behavior evident on a physical device or in Eclipse?

Comment: it's on my device: htc desire

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Page 7 from README.PDF (from MM SDK)

XML Layout

In your layout file, declare the Millennial Media namespace:
xmlns:app="http://millennialmedia.com/android/schema"
Then add the MMAdView and associated meta data you wish to include.

```
<com.millennialmedia.android.MMAdView
      android:id="@+id/mmadview" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      app:apid="28911"
      app:adType="MMBannerAdTop"
      app:refreshInterval="30"
      app:accelerate="true"
      app:ignoreDensityScaling="false"
      app:age="46"
      app:gender="female"
      app:zip="90210"
      app:income="85000"
      app:keywords="moms,shopping,groceries"
      app:ethnicity="hispanic"
      app:orientation="straight"
      app:marital="married"
      app:children="2"
      app:education="college"
      app:politics="libertarian"
      app:height="60"
      app:width="480" />
```

You see? app:width="480"

MM has 5 different ad types:
1. Launch Prestitial
2. Transition Interstitial
3. Top of Page
4. Below the Fold
5. Rectangle

I guess you are interested in nr. 3 and 4. These are located either at the top or at the bottom of the screen and they meant to fill the width in portrait mode. I guess ads from MM have a fixed width so you need to adjust the width of your view. Although, I haven't tried it perhaps playing around with the value of "app:width" may help you.

I have also a Desire and I'm using AdWhirl. First I enabled AdMob with it and then added MM as a 2. network. I also had to adjust the maxWidth/maxHeight of my view because MM ads are quite larger than AdMob ads.

Comment: `app:refreshInterval="30"` Does this auto refresh ad?